# Designing and bitwise, 4 bits 2 inputs a and b

Tags: digital-design

What is the logic of implementing truth table that do bitwise and of two inputs each is 4 bits or how many functions will be output i just need one example please .

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A coded solution or the actual truth table written out?

Comment: @ghDev I am looking for the actual truth table

Comment: Okay. Can you please explain a little bit more clearly what you require? Do you mean you have input A: that could be 0000 0001 0010 ... 1111 and input B: 0000, 0001, 0010, ... 1111?
Which bitwise operation are you looking to execute? Common examples include AND, OR, XOR, ..

Comment: @ghDev Yes i mean that inputs and the operation is and .

Answer (score 0):

You can use an online Python coding playground to find the answers to your truth table.
Here is a link for one: [Python Online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php)

Inside this you can play around with your inputs and then 'execute it' to see the output.

Here are two examples for you to type in. After you type this in, click 'execute' and wait for the results to appear on the right.

```
inputA = 0000
inputB = 0000

print(inputA & inputB)

>>> 0

inputA2 = 1110
inputB2 = 1111

print(inputA2 & inputB2)

>>> 1110
```

You can try to think of a more efficient way to find these values but for now you have a brute-force way to get all of the truth table values by manually changing them.

You can find other bitwise operations for Python here: [Bitwise Operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

To answer the second part, if you have two 4 bit inputs, you can have up to 256 outputs (2^4 * 2^4)